# How do I manipulate the http response using ModelAndView in java?

Tags: java, rest, http, modelandview

I want that when adding a data in the database, the status to be returned is 201 instead of 200. I tried to use the following code but it didn't work:

```
@PostMapping("/salvar")
public ModelAndView salvar(Artigo artigo) {
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView(CADASTRA_ARTIGOS);
    artigoRepository.save(artigo);
    return mv;
}
```

I am also trying to avoid using ResponseEntity.

Comment: StackOverflow work in English, please ask your questions in English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default return status code is `200`. If you want different then you have to use `ResponseEntity` as shown below.

```
@PostMapping("/salvar")
public ModelAndView salvar(Artigo artigo) {
    Artigo artigoSaved = artigoRepository.save(artigo);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(artigoSaved, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```